# cascading Drop Down Error selects 1st item instead of selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Am Using Cascading Drop down In Asp.Net Website But As I Select Third Or Forth Item From Drop down And Save It, It Stores First Value Only.
I filled my form and select Country from country drop down it works smoothly but as i select select country accordingly state drop down is populated and as i select state and click on submit button.
Country selected item is stored as per selection but state drop down always selects first item in the list.

**CODE:**

```
public void FillStates()
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select CountryID, States from States where CountryId = '" + Country.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    State.Items.Clear();
    State.DataSource = dr;
    State.DataTextField = "States";
    State.DataValueField = "CountryID";
    State.DataBind();
    State.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    cn.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();     
}
protected void Country_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    FillStates();
}
```

Comment: Put some code in support of your question. Where are you binding the second dropdown is the problem.

Comment: By looking at your problem it seems like you are binding your any of drop down on page load event without checking the isPostBack!

Comment: add code of first dropdown, how and where you are binding it

Comment: i am feeling my country drop down on page load event with is not post back check

Comment: please reply with your valuable answeres

Comment: Error Solved By Myself .. Thank you for the help.